# Android SQLite - insert query failed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I'm using SQLite to save data in my appliation.
There are no exceptions but the data is not insert to the table.
I get rowId = -1

Is someone can help my?

My definition to the table is:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        " RESULETID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        Constants.COL_1 + " TEXT, " +
        Constants.COL_2 + " TEXT, " +
        Constants.COL_3 + " TEXT, " +
        Constants.COL_4 + " TEXT, " +
        Constants.COL_5 + " TEXT, " +
        Constants.COL_6 + " TEXT)";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + "SCAN_DATE TEXT, ORGAN TEXT, SIDE TEXT, RECOMMENDATION TEXT, CHANGES TEXT)");
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

my insert function is:

```
public boolean insertData(String username, String date, String address, String phone, String recommendation, String changes) {
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Constants.COL_1, username);
    contentValues.put(Constants.COL_2, date);
    contentValues.put(Constants.COL_3, address);
    contentValues.put(Constants.COL_4, phone);
    contentValues.put(Constants.COL_5, recommendation);
    contentValues.put(Constants.COL_6, changes);
    long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    Log.e("InsertData", Long.toString(newRowId));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please post the how you're calling `insertData()` and the exact values of the passed parameters.

Comment: seems like you have changed DB structure try reading this answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218431/database-table-doesnt-exist-according-to-android-studio-compiler/44218537#44218537

Comment: Even when there is no `Exception` thrown you still get logs containing reason for not inserting. Check your logs. Also for easier debugging I'd also suggest `insertOrThrow()`

Comment: you have not created the username column while creating table.

Comment: I did create the usernamr column... as @Pavneet_Singh said I chacnged DB structure. Tnx!