# Strange error with SQLite extending SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've created a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper class and trying to create a DB and insert a dummy record when my Android app launches.

However I get an error 'table gallery has no column named title'.

No error being thrown for the other columns and they're all created in the same way.

The error:

```
12-19 14:24:30.401 4801-4807/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
12-19 14:24:30.808 4801-4801/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) table gallery has no column named title
12-19 14:24:30.810 4801-4801/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting title=First pic artist=James Liscombe rank=3 year=1992
                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table gallery has no column named title (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO gallery(title,artist,rank,year) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                     at com.example.jamesliscombe.cet325assignment.DBHandler.addPicture(DBHandler.java:59)
                                                     at com.example.jamesliscombe.cet325assignment.Home.onCreate(Home.java:35)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The class I've created which extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//DB Info
private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DB_NAME = "louvre";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "gallery";

//Table column names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_RANK = "rank";
private static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_YEAR = "year";

public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_GALLERY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_RANK + "INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ARTIST + "TEXT," + KEY_TITLE + "TEXT," + KEY_YEAR + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_GALLERY_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //Drop older table if it exists
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    //Create table again
    onCreate(db);
}

//Adding a new gallery record
public void addPicture(Picture picture) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_RANK, picture.getRank());
    values.put(KEY_ARTIST, picture.getArtist());
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, picture.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_YEAR, picture.getYear());
    //Insert row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    //Close db connection
    db.close();
}

//Reading a single record
public Picture getPicture(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
        KEY_ID,KEY_RANK,KEY_ARTIST,KEY_TITLE,KEY_YEAR
    },KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {
            String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    Picture contact = new Picture(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
    return contact;
}

//Reading all records
public List<Picture> getAllPictures() {
    List<Picture> galleryList = new ArrayList<Picture>();
    //Select all query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //Loop through all rows and add to galleryList.
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Picture picture = new Picture();
            picture.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            picture.setRank(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            picture.setArtist(cursor.getString(2));
            picture.setTitle(cursor.getString(3));
            picture.setYear(cursor.getString(4));
            galleryList.add(picture);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return galleryList;
}

//Get total number of records
public int getGallerySize() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
    return cursor.getCount();
}

//Update gallery items
public int updateGallery(Picture picture) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_RANK, picture.getRank());
    values.put(KEY_ARTIST, picture.getArtist());
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, picture.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_YEAR, picture.getYear());

    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(picture.getId())});
}

//Delete a gallery record
public void deletePicture(Picture picture) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(picture.getId())});
    db.close();
}
}
```

Where I'm using the class and inserting a dummy record:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //Create our DB
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

    //Insert some test data into our db
    db.addPicture(new Picture(1,3,"James","First pic","1992"));
```

Comment: [uninstall your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218537/4936904)

Comment: There is a space missing between "title" (KEY_TITLE) and "TEXT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a database installed in your device that does not contain `title` column so when your try to add the dummy data with the value for `Title` column, you get the error.

This can be fixed by deleting the old already created database and then running your application again so that new database is created.

To delete the existing database, go to `Android Device Monitor -> data -> data` and then search for your app's package name. Click on your app's package name and then delete the `database` folder inside it and then run your app again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've found the databases folder, however when I click the delete button or click the red minus symbol nothing happens.  Am I missing something obvious haha ?

Comment: Never mind, I deleted the contents in the folder instead

Comment: you need to `right-click` on `database` folder and then click on `delete` option but if you have deleted the contents of the database folder, it will work too

Comment: So I did this, retried and get the same error.  I've extracted the database file, looked inside and can see the title field being created.  This is quite confusing :S Do you have any other suggestions ?  Thanks

Comment: Never mind, tried it again, and this time it worked.  Maybe I looked at an old log.  I shall upvote your answer.  Thanks again for the help