# How to make a favorite column in sqlite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I have a recyclereview that get data from json(online) and make a sqlite database in order to be readable when the user is offline too.i want to make a column that shows this post is in user's favorite list or not.but after i wrote those codes my application can't come up and just crash and in android monitor i have FATAL EXCEPTION that says : no such table:tbl_posts(code1),while compiling:SELECT * FROM tbl_post. what's wrong here?this is my database OpenHelper code:

```
public class PostDatabseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "DatabaseOpenHelper";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="db_post";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

private static final String POST_TABLE_NAME="tbl_posts";


private static final String COL_ID="col_id";

private static final String COL_CONTENT="col_content";
private static final String COL_FAV="0";







private static final String SQL_COMMAND_CREATE_POST_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF 
  NOT EXISTS "+POST_TABLE_NAME+"("+
        COL_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        COL_CONTENT+" TEXT, "+
        COL_FAV+" TEXT);";


Context context;
public PostDatabseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(SQL_COMMAND_CREATE_POST_TABLE);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+e.toString() );
    }


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


public boolean addPost(Post post){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_ID,post.getId());
    cv.put(COL_CONTENT,post.getContent());
    cv.put(COL_FAV,post.getFav());



    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    long isInserted=sqLiteDatabase.insert(POST_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);

    Log.i(TAG, "addPost: "+isInserted);

    if (isInserted>0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public void addPosts(List<Post> posts){
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
        if (!checkPostExists(posts.get(i).getId())) {
            addPost(posts.get(i));
        }
    }
}

public List<Post> getPosts(){
    List<Post>posts=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase =this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+POST_TABLE_NAME,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Post post=new Post();
            post.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            post.setContent(cursor.getString(1));
            post.setFav(cursor.getString(2));

            posts.add(post);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
    sqliteDatabase.close();
    return posts;
}



public  boolean checkPostExists(int postId){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            +POST_TABLE_NAME
            +" WHERE "
            +COL_ID
            +" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(postId)});
    return cursor.moveToFirst();
}




public  boolean setBookFavoriteState(int postId, int state){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_FAV, state);
    long result = sqLiteDatabase.update(
            POST_TABLE_NAME , cv , "id = ?" , new String[] { String.valueOf(postId) }
    );
    if( result < 1 )
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


public int getBookFavoriteState( int id )
{SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + POST_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = '" + id + "'", null
    );

    result.moveToFirst();

    return Integer.parseInt( result.getString( 2 ) );
}}
```

and here is the code that i used in my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

ImageButton btnlike;
PostDatabseOpenHelper daily;
int postid,state;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btnlike = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnlike);
    daily=new PostDatabseOpenHelper(this);


    setupRecyclerView();

    getPostsFromDatabase();




    btnlike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          boolean resulti= daily.setBookFavoriteState(postid,state);

           if (resulti==true){
               btnlike.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.nostar,null));

           }else {
               btnlike.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.star,null));

           }
        }
    });}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218537/4936904

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i did that(manually uninstall the app and installed it again) but no change, again crash and that message

Comment: I don't think there could be any other reason for this issue, make sure you are applying new changes in app, clean project , uninstall manually then try